# Binding Objective C Reference

Tags: objective-c, xamarin

I'm trying to use a binding library (an Objective-C library) in my Xamarin Project. I followed all the instructions in [the documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/Walkthrough_Binding_objective-c_library/).

When I try to use it I can't find it in the edit References/Projects. What do I need to do so that it shows up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the projects are in the same solution, and both projects are of the same type (Xamarin.iOS vs classic) Then it will show up under projects and you can reference it.  Try making sure both of the projects have Xamarin.iOS in the references.